# Another Hadamard matrix of order 4?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, equivalence-relations, hadamard-matrices

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Equivalence_of_Hadamard_matrices) that there is, up to equivalence, a unique Hadamard matrix of order 4, namely

$$
\def\p{\phantom+}
\begin{pmatrix}
\p1&\p1&\p1&\p1 \\
\p1&-1&\p1&-1 \\
\p1&\p1&-1&-1 \\
\p1&-1&-1&\p1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

As *equialence operations* are allowed negating some rows/columns or interchanging some rows/columns.
But isn't the following another Hadamard matrix of order 4 that cannot be obtained in this way?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&\p1&\p1&\p1 \\
\p1&-1&\p1&\p1 \\
\p1&\p1&-1&\p1 \\
\p1&\p1&\p1&-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be obtained that way. Start at the first matrix. Negate first row to get:
$$
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
     1 & -1 &  1 & -1 \\
     1 &  1 & -1 & -1 \\
     1 & -1 & -1 &  1 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Negate colums 2,3,4 to get:
$$
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    -1 &  1 &  1 &  1 \\
     1 &  1 & -1 &  1 \\
     1 & -1 &  1 &  1 \\
     1 &  1 &  1 & -1 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Swap colums 2 and 3. And you get the second matrix.